# Obtener una substing a partir de encontrar determinados caracteres

Tags: python, string, bucle-for

Recurro a este foro porque ya no se por donde encarar el asunto. Resulta que estoy buscando extraer números de teléfono de SQL con python, pero en la columna hay datos mezclados. Tanto números fijos como móviles.

Dado que solo busco extraer los móviles, estoy armando un fragmento de código para que, al detectar los 2 primeros caracteres que determinan los móviles (en argentina, "11" y "15"), me arme una *substing* almacenando cada caracter desde que encuentra esos 2 primeros.

El código es el siguiente:

```
tel="47578392 01152312444"

def search():
    substring=""
    for i in range(len(tel)):
        if tel[i]=="1" and tel[i+1]=="1" or tel[i]=="1" and tel[i+1]=="5":
            substring+=tel[i]

search()
```

El error que me tira es el siguiente:

```
  File "C:/Users/Root1/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/prueba edebug.py", line 6, in search
    if tel[i]=="1" and tel[i+1]=="1" or tel[i]=="1" and tel[i+1]=="5":
IndexError: string index out of range
```

En si mi ida es que, al leer en la casilla de SQL, por ejemplo: `[45450954 1168454565]`

Se quede solo con `[1168454565]`

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Quité la etiqueta SQL que no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta. Además corregí tu mala ortografía.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error surge porque estás recorriendo la cadena hasta el final. Hay un momento en  que `i+1` toma el valor de `len(tel)`, índice que se pasa del final.

El bucle debería ser:

```py
    for i in range(len(tel)-1):
        ...
```

De todos modos, el modo mejor para este tipo de tareas consistentes en aplicar un patrón a una cadena de texto es usar *expresiones regulares* con el módulo `re`:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile("(11|15)\d+")

tel =  "47578392 01152312444"

res = pattern.search(tel)
num = "" if res is None else res.group()
```

Con el patrón `"(11|15)\d+"` estamos buscando una subcadena que empiece por `11` ó `15` seguidos de un número o más `\d+`. Si queremos especificar más, podemos indicar cuántos números estamos buscando: `"(11|15)\d{8}"` para buscar números de 10 dígitos (2 de prefijo + 8 del resto).

Como resultado de `.search()` obtenemos un objeto `re.Match` cuyo método `.group()` nos dará la subcadena, si encuentra una, o `None` si no ha encontrado nada.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ChemaCortes. Me resolviste el problema totalmente, además que profundizaste de tal manera que me sirve para ir entendiendo y mejorando mi programación. Un saludo y gracias de nuevo.